# How to get ExitApp to take effect immediately in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

If I run the following code, if I hit the ^+q it does not stop entering the numbers 1-100. Only after it completes does the script exit. Is there a way to get the script to stop even if it is in the middle of sending keystrokes?

```
^j::
ArrayCount := 100

Loop % ArrayCount
{
Send, %A_index%
}
return

^+q::ExitApp  ; Exit script with Escape key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

`Send`releases modifier keys when it simulates input, using it in a loop this way is going to interfere with autohotkey's hotkey detection. You can still activate `^+q` if you press the 3 buttons simultaneously but it's much easier to use a hotkey without modifiers for example the `Escape` key. This is also what your comment says you're doing

> ^+q::ExitApp  ; **Exit script with Escape key**

so as a bonus it will fix the discrepancy between your comment and your code ;).

The second problem is that the loop in which you execute the `Send` command is going to finish very quickly if you use `SendInput` and by the time `ExitApp` is executed all the numbers were already sent(even if you don't yet see the effect). In case of `SendEvent` there is some other problem which prevents other threads from being executed when you do it in a loop(don't know what causes it, might be a bug).

To solve it you need to add `Sleep`. At my system doing `Sleep 1` works well. You can experiment with different numbers and send modes until you get the desired effect(you can also try `0` and `-1`.

Full code:

```
^j::
ArrayCount := 100
Loop % ArrayCount
{
    Send %A_index%
    Sleep 1 ; experiment with how long to sleep
}
return

Escape::ExitApp  ; Exit script with Escape key
```